# haskell: parse error using higher order functions

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I'm trying to create an insertion sort method that allows me to do an insertion sort based on a function of an item, eg function applied to 1 could be greater than function applied to 2 or vice versa depending on the function.

I have this so far to work out if I can insert an element into a part of a list.

```
insertBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> [a] -> [a] 
insertBy f a [] = [a]
insertBy f a (x:xs) = if ( (f a)< (f x )) then a:x:xs else insertBy f a xs
```

However, I'm getting a parse error on the second line. Sorry if it's really obvious but I can't see it.

Once I have that part I will call an insertion sort function that uses that to sort a list but first I need help with this :(

edit: exact error "Parse error in Pattern insertBy"

Comment: In this kind of question, it would be good if you would give us the error message you're seeing.

Comment: When I insert exactly this text into a module on its own, `ghc` compiles it fine, and does what it's supposed to, including the bug mentioned below.  Same appears to be true for `hugs`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the formatting of the code you have on here. I would guess you have made a typo or some other error in your local copy of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the final expression to be

```
x : insertBy f a xs
```

Otherwise you're discarding the first element of the list in that case.

Comment: yeah you're right but I still get the same error. There is something wrong with line 2

Comment: insertBy is already defined in the haskell library. I fixed it by changing any reference to insertBy to insertBy1. Thanks for that bug also!